# Loop question for Small project to add rows based on count

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Been trying to find information on loops but not really sure where to start to figure out this logic. I want to understand the logic of a loop that achieves the following:

I have a spreadsheet with two columns, column 1 has Work Order #s and Column 2 has Employee Count. I have to assign one break relief employee for every three employees (minimum 3:1 ratio), so I will need to loop over the Employee Count column and add a row once three employees are reached. Here is what I would start with for instance:

```
Work Order #    Employee Count
123                 2
456                 1
101                 3
112                 2
131                 1
161                 5
```

Desired result:

```
Work Order #    Employee Count
[Blank row - Break Relief 1]
123                 2
456                 1
[Blank row - Break Relief 2]
101                 3
[Blank row - Break Relief 3]
112                 2
131                 1
[Blank row - Break Relief 4]
[Blank row - Break Relief 5]
161                 5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In your "Desired result:", can I ask you about the detailed logic that `[Blank row - Break Relief 4]` and `[Blank row - Break Relief 5]` are put between `131                 1` and `161                 5`?

Comment: Yes, there would be two rows added since Work Order #161 has 5 Employees, so in order to meet the 3:1 ratio, it would round up to two Break Reliefs

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(A2:B)` to a cell.

```js
function SAMPLE(v) {
  const limit = 3; // This is from your question.
  v = v.filter(r => r.join(""));
  const { values } = v.reduce((o, [a, b], i, ar) => {
    o.c += b;
    if (o.c <= limit) {
      o.temp.push([a, b]);
    }
    const empty = Math.ceil(o.c / limit);
    if (o.c >= limit || i == ar.length - 1) {
      o.temp = [...Array(empty).fill([null, null]), ...(o.temp.length > 0 ? o.temp : [[a, b]])];
      o.values = [...o.values, ...o.temp];
      o.c = 0;
      o.temp = [];
    }
    return o;
  }, { values: [], temp: [], c: 0 });
  return values;
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- If you don't want to use the script as a custom function, you can also use the following sample script.

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the source sheet name.
      const limit = 3; // This is from your question.
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      const [h, ...v] = sheet.getRange("A1:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r.join(""));
      const { values } = v.reduce((o, [a, b], i, ar) => {
        o.c += b;
        if (o.c <= limit) {
          o.temp.push([a, b]);
        }
        const empty = Math.ceil(o.c / limit);
        if (o.c >= limit || i == ar.length - 1) {
          o.temp = [...Array(empty).fill([null, null]), ...(o.temp.length > 0 ? o.temp : [[a, b]])];
          o.values = [...o.values, ...o.temp];
          o.c = 0;
          o.temp = [];
        }
        return o;
      }, { values: [], temp: [], c: 0 });

      const res = [h, ...values];
      const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // Please set the destination sheet name.
      dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: This works as intended! Thank you! It's a bit above my current Javascript understanding, but I will study some of the things I'm not familiar with and it will help with my current work projects. Thanks again.